# How to get a child value with XPath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have this xml

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <loginResponse xmlns="http://www.tedial.com/3rdparty/" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.tedial.com/apiextension/">
         <session>1C7AE89A-73BF-01E9-9D3F-0010007FFF00</session>
      </loginResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I was trying so many combinations but I am unable to get the session value. Can you help me?

I tried `//S:Envelope//S:Body//ns2:loginResponse//ns2:session` with no luck

Comment: What library/language are you using to execute the xpath query?  Did you include the namespace definition?  Please show the source code

Answer (score 2):

You used a wrong namespace on the `session` element. The default namespace of `loginResponse` - `xmlns="http://www.tedial.com/3rdparty/"` - is inherited to the `session` element. You have to use the same namespace as 
with `loginResponse` which you - erroneously - assigned the `ns2` namespace. So define a third namespace prefix for `http://www.tedial.com/3rdparty/` - here I used `third` - and use that for `loginResponse` and `session`:

```
/S:Envelope/S:Body/third:loginResponse/third:session
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//S:Envelope//S:Body/loginResponse/session/text()
```

ns2 prefix not needed.

Comment: Thanks. This works with some online Xpath tools... but not with all. I am interested in using this SoapUI and it is not working there, unfortunately

Comment: For some reason //S:Envelope//S:Body/loginResponse/session/text() does not work anymore with any tool.....

Comment: I got it working now. The problem was happening in SoapUI. For some reason Soap UI automatically uses namespaces for the default namespaces starting with ns1.
In my case this Xpath expression worked fine:
    //S:Envelope//S:Body//ns1:loginResponse//ns1:session

Comment: This doesn't work because `loginResponse` is not in the default namespace. It needs to have an ns prefix that maps to `http://www.tedial.com/3rdparty/`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. The problem was happening in SoapUI. For some reason Soap UI automatically uses namespaces for the default namespaces starting with ns1. In my case this Xpath expression worked fine: 
    //S:Envelope//S:Body//ns1:loginResponse//ns1:session